# VBA Paste Into Visible Cells only Optimisation

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, cell, visible

So i wrote code that pastes a copied range from the clipboard into the visible cells only starting from the active cell the user marked

I already optimized my code somewhat speeding it up from 7200 Cells/min to 42000 cells/min but i think there still is plenty of room for optimization. But due to the fact that it is the third day programming VB for me i am asking the community for useful tips n tricks for making my code faster

The way i handle it is that i paste the clipboard into an new worksheet 
and then search the next visible cell to insert into i use the variable max length to "limit" the search but in my application thousands of cells may be invisible.

I thought about using a StringBuilder to make it run faster but have no Idea how to implement that

important is that both rows and columns can be invisible

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'Enable Error Handling


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim tblRow1 As Integer, lRow As Integer
Dim tblName As String
Dim lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim outX, outY As Long
Dim maxLength As Long
clipboardTable As String     
outputTable As String  



outputTable = ActiveSheet.Name 'Safe the Name of the target sheet

outY = ActiveCell.Row           'Safe the Target position in sheet with xY coordinates
outX = ActiveCell.Column

 maxLength = Sheets(outputTable).UsedRange.Rows.Count

outYtmp = outY                  'Is needed to reset the corsur from the bottom to top

Set wbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set clipSheet = wbook.Sheets.Add


clipboardTable = clipSheet.Name

Sheets(clipboardTable).Activate
Sheets(clipboardTable).PasteSpecial


'Start Sheet
Sheets(clipboardTable).Select
lastRow = Sheets(clipboardTable).UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastCol = Sheets(clipboardTable).UsedRange.Columns.Count

'MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'MsgBox " " & Sheets(inTable).Rows(1).EntireRow.Hidden



Sheets(outputTable).Select

For x = 1 To lastCol
Sheets(outputTable).Select
For j = 1 To maxLength
    If Sheets(outputTable).Columns(outX).Hidden = False Then
        For y = 1 To lastRow
            For i = 1 To maxLength
                If Sheets(outputTable).Rows(outY).Hidden = False Then

                    Sheets(outputTable).Cells([outY], [outX]) = Sheets(clipboardTable).Cells([y], [x])
                    outY = outY + 1
                    Exit For

                End If
            outY = outY + 1
            Next
        Next

        outX = outX + 1
        Exit For
    End If
 outX = outX + 1
Next
outY = outYtmp

Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(clipboardTable).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:  ' Error-handling routine.
    If (Worksheets(clipboardTable).Name <> "") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(clipboardTable).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of saving the name property of the worksheet to a string variable and then using it with sheets() or worksheets(), why not set an object reference to that particular worksheet? Not an optimisation, although it means the sheet name no longer needs resolving within the nested loop -- especially since the value of outputTable does not change within the loop.

Comment: Also, you should probably avoid using `select` and `avoid` if you're looking to optimise -- and using arrays may improve speed too depending on use case.

Comment: @chillin I tried "simple" 2D arrays but it took more than twice the time to compute 
the code I wrote will copy 100s of thousends cells at once and ten it starts to take many minutes